# A graph having vertex degree 3 has no decomposition into paths with atleast 5 vertices each.

Tags: graph-theory

Seeing its solution , i am **not able** to get in many points (written below in **bold** )

Solution is like-:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose  that  $G$  has  such a decompostion . Since every vertex have degree $3$,each vertex is endpoint of atleast one of the path.(**does it applies to even number of vertices too ?**) ** and is the internal vertex on atmost one of them.

$\Rightarrow$Since every path in the decomposition has two wo endpoints and atleast $3$ internal vertices ,we can conclude that **number of path in the decomposition is atleast $\frac {n\left(G\right)} {2} $
 and atmost $\frac {n\left(G\right)} {3} $** .

Please help me out  ..it would be easier for me to understand if one explain with example including figure !

Comment: If the graph is 3-regular, _there are by definition no even vertices_.

Comment: I mean if there are even vertices ,(odd regular graph )  @HenningMakholm

Comment: A 3-regular graph always has an even number of vertices (otherwise it would have an odd number of half-edges, which is absurd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different telling of essentially the same argument:

Suppose the graph decomposes into $k$ such paths.

These paths have, taken together, at least $3k$ internal vertices, and each vertex that is the internal vertex of some path must also be the endpoint of one path (because it has degree $3$).

So there are *at least* $3k$ nodes that are endpoints of paths. On the other hand, the $k$ paths have only $2k$ end points all in all. Since $2k$ is less than $3k$, this cannot be.